# How to create a list with three columns in a row by css and html?

Tags: html, css

I am making a list that is similar as the sample

[image]

I tried to make css code to build a list style as above. However, my output does not look like it. Could you help me to look at my css and html and help me to obtain it?

This is my current output
[image]

This is what I tried. You can see the online demo at [here](http://liveweave.com/#&togetherjs=n1r87P7pcx)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="view"> 
                <div id="container">
                    <ul>
                        <!-- row 01 -->
                        <a href="#"><li class="clearfix">
                                <h2>Wordpress desiger</h2>
                                <p class="desc">Wordpress and beyond </p>  
                                <p class="location">NY.</p>
                                <p class="time">Jan.</p>
                                <span class="jobtype">Part time</span>
                        </li></a>

                        <!-- row 02 -->
                        <a href="#"><li class="clearfix">

                            <h2>CEO</h2>
                            <p class="desc">Think different</p>
                            <p class="location">Denver</p>
                            <p class="time">Feb.</p>
                            <span class="jobtype">Contract</span>
                        </li></a>

                        <!-- row 03 -->
                        <a href="#"><li class="clearfix">                            
                            <h2>Interactive desiger</h2>
                            <p class="desc">Designer.</p>  
                            <p class="location">NY.</p> 
                            <p class="time">May</p>
                            <span class="jobtype">Full time</span>
                        </li></a>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>



</div>   
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS code is

```
body{
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
body.is-ontop{
    margin-top: 53px;
}
h1{
    font-size: 44px;
}
h2{
    font-size: 20px;
}
h3{
    font-size: 18px;
}
a{
    color: #666;
}
a:hover{
    color: #ff3366;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.25s;
}
a:focus{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.bold{
  font-weight: bold;
}  
a { text-decoration: none; }

/** content display **/
#view { display: block; padding: 0; margin: 0; height:600px;  overflow:hidden; overflow-y:scroll;}
#container { display: block; margin-top: 10px; }
#container ul { }
#container ul a li { 
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
    border-top: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
    background: #FFF;

}

#container ul a { display: block; position: relative; width: 100%; }
#container ul li h2 { font-size: 2.1em; line-height: 1.3em; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: -0.03em; padding-top: 4px; color: #55678d; }
#container ul li p.desc { color: #555; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 1.3em; line-height: 1.3em; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; }
#container ul li p.location { color: #555; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 1.3em; line-height: 1.3em; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; }
#container ul li p.time { color: #555; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 1.3em; line-height: 1.3em; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; }
}#container ul li .jobtype { position: absolute; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; font-size: 1.2em; font-weight: bold; color: #6ea247; }  
#container ul a:hover li h2 { color: #7287b1; }
#container ul a:hover li p.desc { color: #757575; }    
#container ul a:hover li {
background: #E8EAEA;
}
```

Comment: Use table of three column and generate your UI inside table

Comment: Or, try bootstrap this will be better and responsive as well

Comment: @NitinDhomse: How can you use table or bootstrap to obtain my expected result? Could you show it in answer with code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use tables. It's 2016. Also just a pointer, a tags are usually inside li tags.

```css
ul a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul a .information {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

h2, .job-type {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="view"> 
                <div id="container">
                    <ul>
                        <!-- row 01 -->
                        <a href="#"><li class="clearfix">
                                <h2>Wordpress desiger</h2>
                                <div class="information">
                                <p class="desc">Wordpress and beyond </p>  
                                <p class="location">NY.</p>
                                <p class="time">Jan.</p>
                                </div>
                                <span class="jobtype">Part time</span>
                        </li></a>

                        <!-- row 02 -->
                        <a href="#"><li class="clearfix">

                            <h2>CEO</h2>
                            <div class="information">
                            <p class="desc">Think different</p>
                            <p class="location">Denver</p>
                            <p class="time">Feb.</p>
                            </div>
                            <span class="jobtype">Contract</span>
                        </li></a>

                        <!-- row 03 -->
                        <a href="#"><li class="clearfix">                            
                            <h2>Interactive desiger</h2>
                            <div class="information">
                            <p class="desc">Designer.</p>  
                            <p class="location">NY.</p> 
                            <p class="time">May</p>
                            </div>
                            <span class="jobtype">Full time</span>
                        </li></a>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>



</div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great. Is it possible to make the location and date in the center between top and bottom of a row?

Comment: Yep, you just have to fix the margins. I didn't apply any styles, I just showed you the basic layout. I updated the codepen to reflect the changes.

Comment: haha "it's 2016" lovely  wish i could say that to our client

Comment: @moesphemie Dude tell me about it. Half of the time I can't use flex because clients are grandpas that still use IE9. Makes me want to kms.

Comment: haha don't lose hope. Found this polyfill some weeks ago: https://github.com/jonathantneal/flexibility - maybe it's something for you

Answer (score 1):

I personally like to use the Lemonade CSS grid,
I think if you built it using this, it would a lot more easier to get the look your going for. It say prebuilt styles to help you accomplish it.

This might help you visualize the divs using lemonade.
[image]

Here is the link for lemonade http://lemonade.im/

Answer (score 0):

Try to simulate de comportament of the tag table, or you can use display flex to make your grid more flexible
 Ex:

```
<ul>
    <li class="row">
        <a href="#">

            <div class="td function">
                <h2>Wordpress desiger</h2>
                <p class="desc">Wordpress and beyond </p>
                <span class="jobtype">Part time</span>
            </div>

            <div class="td location">
                <p>NY.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="td time">
                <p class="time">Jan.</p>
            </div>

        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS ex:

```
.row a{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.td{
  padding: 5px;
}

.function{
  width: 60%;
}
.location,.time{
  width: 20%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:inline` for the li's:

```
ul.inline-list {width:100%;}

ul.inline-list li {display:inline; width:33%;}
```

then assign `class="inline-list"` to the `ul`.